# Is there a way to combine armatures in a way that doesn't result in duplicate bones?

Tags: armature

I have a model that for some reason is arbitrarily broken in two parts and both parts have their own armatures. Both armatures have some bones unique to that armature, but most bones are present in both armatures. I can't use Ctrl + J to combine the armatures, because I'll then have overlapping bones (each of them still control their own part of the mesh even though they are in the same armature). Is there any good way of fixing this without having to redo the entire armature or do some pretty extensive editing to it?

Comment: With a script you can merge the bones of the two armatures. Just ignore the bones that already exists... - or delete them, then you can join the armatures with Ctrl+J.